# Convert dataframe column to datetime for re-mapping

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a bunch of weather data that I need to remap with Pandas.
I'm struggling to convert the first column 'Time' to a datetime index.
I've been scanning forums, and have not been able to fix the problem.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
Time    TemperatureF    DewpointF

1/1/2015 0:01   31.7    27.1

1/1/2015 0:06   31.7    27.4

1/1/2015 0:11   31.6    27.3

1/1/2015 0:16   31.6    27.3

1/1/2015 0:21   31.5    26.9

1/1/2015 0:26   31.5    26.9

1/1/2015 0:31   31.5    26.9
```

and here is the most recent version of the code I'm using to re-index.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
df = df.set_index('Time')
df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
```

Comment: What problem do you have?  Errors, etc.

Comment: Can you please show the results of 1) `df.head(2)`, 2) `df.Time.iat[0]` and 3) `type(df.Time.iat[0])`  Thank you.

Comment: 1) <bound method NDFrame.head of 2) AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time' 3) Same  Thanks for you interest/help!

Comment: That implies your data is not like your sample above.  Did you include `(2)` after `head`, which should return the first two rows.  What is the output of `df.iloc[:5]` (which should print the first five rows of the dataframe)

Comment: i would also suggest you to post the result of `df.columns.tolist()` command, beside those suggested by @Alexander

Comment: Better yet, `df.info()`

Comment: df.iloc[:5] 
            Time TemperatureF DewpointF PressureIn WindDirection  \
0  1/1/2015 0:01         31.7      27.1      30.44           ENE   
1  1/1/2015 0:06         31.7      27.4      30.44           ENE   
2  1/1/2015 0:11         31.6      27.3      30.44           ENE   
3  1/1/2015 0:16         31.6      27.3      30.44           ENE   
4  1/1/2015 0:21         31.5      26.9      30.44           ENE

Comment: Is there a space in the column name 'Time'?  For example, is it 'Time  '? `df.columns[0]` should reveal that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print df
            Time  TemperatureF  DewpointF
0  1/1/2015 0:01          31.7       27.1
1  1/1/2015 0:06          31.7       27.4
2  1/1/2015 0:11          31.6       27.3
3  1/1/2015 0:16          31.6       27.3
4  1/1/2015 0:21          31.5       26.9
5  1/1/2015 0:26          31.5       26.9
6  1/1/2015 0:31          31.5       26.9

#check column names
print df.columns
Index([u'Time', u'TemperatureF', u'DewpointF'], dtype='object')

#first number is month
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') #no double []

df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
print df
                     TemperatureF  DewpointF
Time                                        
2015-01-01 00:01:00          31.7       27.1
2015-01-01 00:06:00          31.7       27.4
2015-01-01 00:11:00          31.6       27.3
2015-01-01 00:16:00          31.6       27.3
2015-01-01 00:21:00          31.5       26.9
2015-01-01 00:26:00          31.5       26.9
2015-01-01 00:31:00          31.5       26.9

print df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:01:00', '2015-01-01 00:06:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:11:00', '2015-01-01 00:16:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:21:00', '2015-01-01 00:26:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:31:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Time', freq=None)
```

If still `ValueError`, try add parameter `errors='coerce'` for converting strings not matching format to `NaT`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')
```

Comment: When I add the suggested code I receive an error: ValueError: Unknown string format

Comment: df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce')

the errors='coerce' seems to have been the key! 

Thank you, this worked beautifully!

Comment: Make sure you check the results because you'll loose data if you just suppress error messages instead of trying to properly parse: If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT. Alternatively, if you have no NaT values, the `errors='coerce'` didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pd.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead of `df.index.to_datetime()`, and use the result as your `index`.

If the format does not convert correctly, you'll  need to add a `format` parameter that uses [these](http://strftime.org/) naming conventions, e.g. `format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Time']]) # Convert 'Time' column to datetime, possibly using format keyword
df.set_index(df.Time, inplace=True) # set result as index
```

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: "arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series"

Comment: df[['Time']] should give you a `pd.Series` unless you've already set it to index. What are you getting instead?

Comment: KeyError: "['Time'] not in index"

Comment: Does `df.info()` show that you have a column called `Time`? The above only works before you set `Time` as index.

Comment: Index: 98764 entries, 1/1/2015 0:01 to 12/31/2015 23:59 \ Data columns (total 15 columns) : \ Temperature F \ DewpointF .... etc

Comment: To use the above, first do `.reset_index()`. Then you should see `Time` as column. Alternatively, you could try `df.index = pd.DateTimeIndex(df.index)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df.Time)), inplace=True)
```

Comment: I'm still getting "TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>" & "ValueError: Unknown string format"